# Bundle forked gem pulls old version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, fork, bundler

I forked the geokit gem on github. Now when I add this gem to my Gemfile and then bundle on the server, the gem is downloaded, but without my committed and pushed changes. What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to git.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'geokit', :git => 'git://github.com/jan/geokit-gem.git'
```

And I double-checked, that the changes have been comitted and pushed to github, e.g.:
https://github.com/jan/geokit-gem/blob/master/lib/geokit.rb requires 'geokit/mappable' before 'geokit/geocoders' instead of vice versa.

I go to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/geokit-gem-e60b6c1f1f29 and do a git pull it actually pulls my changes. So I assume my git has, like, an old version set to be the current version?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gemfile.lock contains a revision for gems loaded via git:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/jan/geokit-gem.git
  revision: e60b6c1f1f2931209533c78f0a1ecac500302c50
  specs:
    geokit (1.5.0)
```

So I had to bundle update geokit. Kind of obvious in retrospect, but I didn't think of it that day. Hope it helps somebody.